# mock a method that is called by another method

Tags: java, mockito

my class

```
class X {
    protected int a() { return 1; }
    protected int b() { return a(); }
}
```

My test code

```
X x = mock(X.class)
when (x.a()).thenReturn(100);
// System.out.println(x.a());
assertEquals(100, x.b());
```

The assert fails as `a()` from within `b()` is still returning 1.
if I uncomment the debug line, 100 is printed. But the assert still fails with a 1.

What am I doing wrong here?  I expected `x.a()` to return 100 in all cases, not only when I call it directly.

Comment: Your test could simply be `assertEquals(1, x.b())` without any mocks.

Comment: @knittl this is a boiled-down example.

Comment: What are you really testing, if you are changing the behavior of your thing under test? Are you testing your real thing or are you testing an almost-real-but-not-quite version of it?

Comment: In reality `a()` is has a static reference that really should be injected instead. But this is legacy code and plenty of it, and I want to write a test without refactoring the world.  I am indeed testing `b()`'s behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Best practices say you should either mock an object entirely or not at all. Thus, Mockito mocks every single method of the mocked object. If you want to mock only some methods, you have to tell it which methods you *don't* want to mock:

```
when (x.a()).thenReturn(100);
when (x.b()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

This is called a partial mock. Read more about it in section 16 of the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Answer (score 2):

Mockito has to be configured to use partial mocking aproach.

The class has to be tested:

```java
public class Something {

    protected int a() {
        return 1;
    }

    protected int b() {
        return a();
    }
}
```

#### Solution A - Using mock()

```java
class SomethingTest {

    @Test
    void mockTest() {
        var mock = mock(Something.class);

        when(mock.a()).thenReturn(100); // mocking method call a()
        when(mock.b()).thenCallRealMethod(); // call the real implementation
        assertEquals(100, mock.b());
        assertEquals(100, mock.a());
    }
}
```

#### Solution B - Using spy()

Spied object calls the real methods unless they are stubbed.

```java
class SomethingTest {

    @Test
    void spyTest() {
        var spy = spy(Something.class);
        when(spy.a()).thenReturn(100);
        assertEquals(100, spy.b());
        assertEquals(100, spy.a());
    }
}
```